# tick tac toe against computer

Tags: c#, tic-tac-toe

So I programmed an Tic Tac Toe game. At this moment it is an person vs person game. Now I want that the computer is the one person so "person vs computer" I already programmed the computer that it should answer the game,  but its still person vs person. How can I change my programm so, that the computer is answering?

the code for the Tic Tac Toe is this:

```
bool turn = true;
int tic_counter = 0;
public Baden()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button_click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    if (turn)
        b.Text = "X";
    else
        b.Text = "O";
        computer_make_move();

    turn = !turn;
    b.Enabled = false;
    tic_counter++;

    CheckForWinner();    
}

private void CheckForWinner()
{
    bool there_is_a_winner = false;

    if ((A1.Text == A2.Text) && (A2.Text == A3.Text) && (!A1.Enabled))
        there_is_a_winner = true;
    else if ((B1.Text == B2.Text) && (B2.Text == B3.Text) && (!B1.Enabled))
        there_is_a_winner = true;
    else if ((C1.Text == C2.Text) && (C2.Text == C3.Text) && (!C1.Enabled))
        there_is_a_winner = true;



    if ((A1.Text == B1.Text) && (B1.Text == C1.Text) && (!A1.Enabled))
        there_is_a_winner = true;
    else if ((B2.Text == A2.Text) && (A2.Text == C2.Text) && (!A2.Enabled))
        there_is_a_winner = true;
    else if ((C3.Text == A3.Text) && (A3.Text == B3.Text) && (!A3.Enabled))
        there_is_a_winner = true;


    if ((A1.Text == B2.Text) && (B2.Text == C3.Text) && (!A1.Enabled))
        there_is_a_winner = true;
    else if ((B2.Text == A3.Text) && (A3.Text == C1.Text) && (!B2.Enabled))
        there_is_a_winner = true;


    if (there_is_a_winner)
    {
        disableButtons();
        String winner = "";
        if (turn)
            winner = "O";
        else
            winner = "X";

        MessageBox.Show("Der gewinner ist: " + winner);
        this.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        if(tic_counter == 9)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unentschieden!");
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And the Computer is this:

```
private void computer_make_move()
{
    //priority 1:  get tick tac toe
    //priority 2:  block x tic tac toe
    //priority 3:  go for corner space
    //priority 4:  pick open space

    Button move = null;

    //look for tic tac toe opportunities
    move = look_for_win_or_block("O"); //look for win
    if (move == null)
    {
        move = look_for_win_or_block("X"); //look for block
        if (move == null)
        {
            move = look_for_corner();
            if (move == null)
            {
                move = look_for_open_space();
            }
        }

    }
    move.PerformClick();

}

private Button look_for_open_space()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Looking for open space");
    Button b = null;
    foreach (Control c in Controls)
    {
        b = c as Button;
        if (b != null)
        {
            if (b.Text == "")
                return b;
        }//end if
    }//end if

    return null;
}

private Button look_for_corner()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Looking for corner");
    if (A1.Text == "O")
    {
        if (A3.Text == "")
            return A3;
        if (C3.Text == "")
            return C3;
        if (C1.Text == "")
            return C1;
    }

    if (A3.Text == "O")
    {
        if (A1.Text == "")
            return A1;
        if (C3.Text == "")
            return C3;
        if (C1.Text == "")
            return C1;
    }

    if (C3.Text == "O")
    {
        if (A1.Text == "")
            return A3;
        if (A3.Text == "")
            return A3;
        if (C1.Text == "")
            return C1;
    }

    if (C1.Text == "O")
    {
        if (A1.Text == "")
            return A3;
        if (A3.Text == "")
            return A3;
        if (C3.Text == "")
            return C3;
    }

    if (A1.Text == "")
        return A1;
    if (A3.Text == "")
        return A3;
    if (C1.Text == "")
        return C1;
    if (C3.Text == "")
        return C3;

    return null;
}

private Button look_for_win_or_block(string mark)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Looking for win or block:  " + mark);
    //HORIZONTAL TESTS
    if ((A1.Text == mark) && (A2.Text == mark) && (A3.Text == ""))
        return A3;
    if ((A2.Text == mark) && (A3.Text == mark) && (A1.Text == ""))
        return A1;
    if ((A1.Text == mark) && (A3.Text == mark) && (A2.Text == ""))
        return A2;

    if ((B1.Text == mark) && (B2.Text == mark) && (B3.Text == ""))
        return B3;
    if ((B2.Text == mark) && (B3.Text == mark) && (B1.Text == ""))
        return B1;
    if ((B1.Text == mark) && (B3.Text == mark) && (B2.Text == ""))
        return B2;

    if ((C1.Text == mark) && (C2.Text == mark) && (C3.Text == ""))
        return C3;
    if ((C2.Text == mark) && (C3.Text == mark) && (C1.Text == ""))
        return C1;
    if ((C1.Text == mark) && (C3.Text == mark) && (C2.Text == ""))
        return C2;

    //VERTICAL TESTS
    if ((A1.Text == mark) && (B1.Text == mark) && (C1.Text == ""))
        return C1;
    if ((B1.Text == mark) && (C1.Text == mark) && (A1.Text == ""))
        return A1;
    if ((A1.Text == mark) && (C1.Text == mark) && (B1.Text == ""))
        return B1;

    if ((A2.Text == mark) && (B2.Text == mark) && (C2.Text == ""))
        return C2;
    if ((B2.Text == mark) && (C2.Text == mark) && (A2.Text == ""))
        return A2;
    if ((A2.Text == mark) && (C2.Text == mark) && (B2.Text == ""))
        return B2;

    if ((A3.Text == mark) && (B3.Text == mark) && (C3.Text == ""))
        return C3;
    if ((B3.Text == mark) && (C3.Text == mark) && (A3.Text == ""))
        return A3;
    if ((A3.Text == mark) && (C3.Text == mark) && (B3.Text == ""))
        return B3;

    //DIAGONAL TESTS
    if ((A1.Text == mark) && (B2.Text == mark) && (C3.Text == ""))
        return C3;
    if ((B2.Text == mark) && (C3.Text == mark) && (A1.Text == ""))
        return A1;
    if ((A1.Text == mark) && (C3.Text == mark) && (B2.Text == ""))
        return B2;

    if ((A3.Text == mark) && (B2.Text == mark) && (C1.Text == ""))
        return C1;
    if ((B2.Text == mark) && (C1.Text == mark) && (A3.Text == ""))
        return A3;
    if ((A3.Text == mark) && (C1.Text == mark) && (B2.Text == ""))
        return B2;

    return null;
}
```

So how can I change the programm, that the computer is answering now?

Comment: Welcome to AI 101. [Minimax search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
private void button_click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var oldTurn = turn;

    Button b = (Button)sender;
    if (turn)
        b.Text = "X";
    else
        b.Text = "O";

    turn = !turn;

    //try to remove this line since it will block PerformClick in computer_make_move()
    //don't know for sure if that is the button that gets "clicked" in Computer
    //b.Enabled = false;

    tic_counter++;
    CheckForWinner();

    if (oldTurn)
        computer_make_move();
}
```

If you need the button to be disabled, you can extract your code into a differnent method and call this instead of `PerformClick`

```
private void button_click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     ExecuteButtonCode(sender);
}

private void ExecuteButtonCode(object sender)
{
    var oldTurn = turn;

    Button b = (Button)sender;
    if (turn)
        b.Text = "X";
    else
        b.Text = "O";

    turn = !turn;

    b.Enabled = false;

    tic_counter++;
    CheckForWinner();

    if (oldTurn)
        computer_make_move();
}
```

And in your `computer_make_move` call this:

```
ExecuteButtonCode(move);
```

instead of

```
move.PerformClick();
```

You will need to block the exectution of your `computer_make_move();` if the game is over.

Change your `CheckForWinner` method to this - (removed some code, so that it's easier to see where I put code, placed comments where I removed code):

```
private bool gameIsOver = false; //boolean to track if the game is over or not
private void CheckForWinner()
{
    bool there_is_a_winner = false;

    //[RemovedCode] - Evaluation of your buttons...

    if (there_is_a_winner)
    {
        gameIsOver = true;
        //[RemovedCode] - winning code...
    }
    else
    {
        if(tic_counter == 9)
        {
            gameIsOver = true;
            //[RemovedCode] - losing code...
        }
    }
}
```

And now add the check if the game is over, to your method:

```
private void ExecuteButtonCode(object sender)
{
    if (gameIsOver)
        return; //return (exit) the method if the game is over and just do nothing in that case

    var oldTurn = turn;

    Button b = (Button)sender;
    if (b == null)
        return; //return (exit) the method if b is null to prevent the NullReferenceException from occuring

    if (turn)
        b.Text = "X";
    else
        b.Text = "O";

    turn = !turn;

    b.Enabled = false;

    tic_counter++;
    CheckForWinner();

    if (gameIsOver)
        return; //return (exit) the method if the game is over, to prevent computer from making a move

    if (oldTurn)
        computer_make_move();
}
```

Comment: ok this is close. It works if I press 2 buttons. So I do once X turn and then once O turn, then the computer does is X turn

Comment: than it should be `if (oldTurn)` instead of `if (!oldTurn)`

Comment: it works so long someone won, if no one won it says that "b was null" System.NullReferenceException: "The object reference was not set to an object instance."

Comment: Well the only code that you have in the losing branch is `if(tic_counter == 9)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unentschieden!");
            this.Close();
        }` - but there can't be a NullReferenceExpction - can you say what line this excption occurs while debugging your code?

Comment: Okay, I think I figured what is going wrong - I will update my code.

Comment: its in "else b.Text = "O";"     the messageBox showing up but after Im clicking ok then the Problem showing up there

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it event based with you clicks, the easiest way is to change the button click event to something like this:
private void button_click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

```
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    if (turn)
        b.Text = "X";
    else
        b.Text = "O";

    b.Enabled = false;
    tic_counter++;
    turn = !turn;
    CheckForWinner();

    if (!turn)
        computer_make_move();
}
```

Now everytime it's the players turn it will directly do a computer move. Keeping the computer_make_move in the else path would mean, that you have to click on a button to execute the computer code, which then leads to another click.

Comment: yeah ok I changed it like that but it still don't work sadly

Comment: if you step through, does the the event get triggered twice?

Answer (score 0):

One of the tricks that will greatly help out programming stuff like this is: *don't put substantial code in the event functions.*

Here's your general code structure:

```
mouseClickEvent()
{
    // lines of code to handle stuff
    // lines of code to check for a winner
    // lines of code to have the computer decide a move
    // calling mouseClickEvent() for the computer.
}
```

... and you're running into problems because mouseClickEvent() is being called from two different sources: by the user clicking a button, and from being called from within the code.

Well, there's a relatively easy fix:

```
void mouseClickEvent(...)
{
    HandlePlayerSelectingSquare(playerNum: 1, source: sender);
}
void HandlePlayerSelectingSquare(int playerNum, Object source)
{
    // misc stuff
    // if playerNum == 0, return - we don't need to continue on
    // figure out a computer move
    // call HandlePlayerSelectingSquare(2, computersButtonChoice)
}
```

... make sense?  Now you've got an easy way of telling whether the player or the computer is making their choice: by the playerNum being passed in to the function (the event will never be called by the computer.)